# Rails default key provider error only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-sdk, production-environment, activesupport

I am trying to run my rails project in production environment, I've already checked the .env file, tested on my development environment, but when goes to production environment I get that stack trace.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/activesupport-4.1.16/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.30.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/encryption/default_key_provider.rb:31: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.30.0/lib/aws-sdk-s3/encryption/default_key_provider.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
        def key�for(materials_description)
                ^ (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were rewriting directly the `aws-sdk-s3` gem. This is not recommended. If you want a custom behavior for that gem, you should fork it or clone the project and make a custom branch for that. If it's not the case, you can update the gem to the latest version also.

Having said that, the error is in method name. Look this:

```
def key�for(materials_description)
```

The best way to fix it is removing the line and write it again like this:

```
def key_for(materials_description)
```

Comment: I am not trying to rewrite the gem, actually I delete all gems and run bundle again.